# Do encoders benefit from monochrome videos? Are they more efficient?

Tags: streaming, video-encoding

Let's suppose that i can stream a color video at 480p, due to bandwidth issues, i can't stream a higher resolution.

Can i expect to be able to stream a 720p video, if i cut the colors off?

What encoders would theoretically support this and do you suggest me to try this?

Comment: Are you talking about turning 24 bit RGB into 8 bit (or 24 bit?) monochrome prior to encoding?

Comment: Is this a programming related question?

Comment: You are right, it's not.